# how to show a google map view in django admin view for a polygon field

Tags: django, google-maps, django-admin, gis, geodjango

I've been trying to show google map view for a polygon field in my django admin view without using olwidget.
But against geom field I get a blank view. No map widget.

I am upgrading django version in my app from 1.3 to 1.10 and need to keep compatibility with both versions so cannot use olwidget(not compatible with django 1.10). I was using olwidget to show google map widget in django 1.3 version env.

In Django 1.10 there is a OSMGeoAdmin class but that doesn't give me the view that is in my second image link.

So, need a way to show google map view that works in both versions of django.

```
from django.contrib.gis.maps.google import GoogleMap
from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class GoogleMapAdmin(GeoModelAdmin):
    GMAP = GoogleMap(api_url="api-url")
    map_template = 'gis/google/google-map.html'

class MyMapModelAdmin(GoogleMapAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', )
    list_map = ['geom']

class MyMapModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom = models.PolygonField()
```

[blank view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GCD2.png)

[previous view using olwidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHJlS.png)